# Using KinectColorViewer in SDK1.5

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I am trying to use a KinectColorViewer in a project using Kinect for windows (sdk 1.5). In the kinect explorer example, the KinectColorViewer componant had a KinectSensorManager component that is binded. In the xaml file we have:

```
<kt:KinectColorViewer x:Name="ColorViewer" KinectSensorManager="{Binding KinectSensorManager}" CollectFrameRate="True" RetainImageOnSensorChange="True" />
```

I have a lot of trouble reproduccing the same concept in other projects. I have used the Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit's KinectSensorChooser, KinectSensorChooserUI and the Mirosoft.Sampels.Kinect.wpfviewers KinectColorViewer. Tried to bind the KinectSensorManager of The colorViewer to the UI element and follows.

```
<my:KinectColorViewer Width="200" Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="198,12,0,0" Name="kinectColorViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" KinectSensorManager="{Binding ElementName=kinectSensorChooserUI1, Path=KinectSensorChooser.Kinect}" />
```

both attempts were unsuccesfull. Has anyone used the ColorViwer, DepthViwer and SkeletonViewer using the new SDK? Figuring that our would be great...

To bind the KinectSensorManager, I added the following code to the back end:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public KinectSensorManager KinectSensorManager { get; set;}
  private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  KinectSensorManager = new KinectSensorManager();

  KinectSensorManager.KinectSensorChanged += new EventHandler<KinectSensorManagerEventArgs<KinectSensor>>(KinectSensorManager_KinectSensorChanged);

        // Look through all sensors and start the first connected one.
        // This requires that a Kinect is connected at the time of app startup.
        foreach (var potentialSensor in KinectSensor.KinectSensors)
        {
            if (potentialSensor.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
            {
                this.sensor = potentialSensor;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (null != this.sensor)
        {
            // Turn on the skeleton stream to receive skeleton frames

            this.sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
            this.sensor.DepthStream.Enable();
            this.sensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
            this.sensor.AllFramesReady += new System.EventHandler<AllFramesReadyEventArgs>(sensor_AllFramesReady);
            this.sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += this.SensorSkeletonFrameReady;

            // Start the sensor!
            try
            {
                this.sensor.Start();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                this.sensor = null;
            }

            var kinectSensorBinding = new Binding("KinectSensor") { Source = this.sensor };
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.KinectSensorManager, KinectSensorManager.KinectSensorProperty, kinectSensorBinding);

        }

        if (null == this.sensor)
        {
            this.statusBarText.Text = Properties.Resources.NoKinectReady;
        }

    }
```

and the Xaml file:

```
<kt:KinectColorViewer Width="191" Height="83" Grid.Column="3" KinectSensorManager="{Binding KinectSensorManager}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,236,0,0" Name="kinectColorViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

but I still dont get any color stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You binding statement is incorrect.  "KinectSensorChooser.Kinect" is a reference to hardware (i.e., the Kinect) selected by the KinectSensorChooser -- it is not the KinectSensorManager.

You should be binding to the KinectSensorManager in the same way the examples show you.  Is there something special you are trying to do that would lead you to bind it differently?

Your main class should start out something like this:

```
// automatically finds a Kinect for you
private readonly KinectSensorChooser sensorChooser = new KinectSensorChooser();

// the bindable sensor property
public KinectSensorManager KinectSensorManager { get; private set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
    if (IsInDesignMode) {
        // load design mode only content
    }
    else
    {
        // initialize the Kinect sensor manager
        KinectSensorManager = new KinectSensorManager();
        KinectSensorManager.KinectSensorChanged += this.KinectSensorChanged;

        // locate an available sensor
        sensorChooser.Start();

        // bind chooser's sensor value to the local sensor manager
        var kinectSensorBinding =
            new Binding("Kinect") { Source = this.sensorChooser };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(
            this.KinectSensorManager,
            KinectSensorManager.KinectSensorProperty,
            kinectSensorBinding);
    }
}

#region Kinect Discovery & Setup

private void KinectSensorChanged(object sender,
    KinectSensorManagerEventArgs<KinectSensor> args)
{
    if (null != args.OldValue)  
        UninitializeKinectServices(args.OldValue);

    if (null != args.NewValue)
        InitializeKinectServices(KinectSensorManager, args.NewValue);
}

// Kinect enabled apps should customize which Kinect services it initializes here.
private void InitializeKinectServices(
    KinectSensorManager kinectSensorManager, 
    KinectSensor sensor)
{
    // Application should enable all streams first.

    // configure the color stream
    kinectSensorManager.ColorFormat = 
        ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30;
    kinectSensorManager.ColorStreamEnabled = true;

    // configure the depth stream
    kinectSensorManager.DepthStreamEnabled = true;

    kinectSensorManager.TransformSmoothParameters = 
        new TransformSmoothParameters
        {
            Smoothing = 0.5f,
            Correction = 0.5f,
            Prediction = 0.5f,
            JitterRadius = 0.05f,
            MaxDeviationRadius = 0.04f
        };

    // configure the skeleton stream
    sensor.SkeletonFrameReady += OnSkeletonFrameReady;
    kinectSensorManager.SkeletonStreamEnabled = true;
}

// Kinect enabled apps should uninitialize all Kinect services that were initialized in InitializeKinectServices() here.
private void UninitializeKinectServices(KinectSensor sensor)
{
    sensor.SkeletonFrameReady -= this.OnSkeletonFrameReady;
}

#endregion Kinect Discovery & Setup
```

You can then bind to the manager from your View as shown by the examples.

You make need to also set the DataContext, by putting the following into the constructor:
    DataContext = this;

Comment: Thank you very much for replying to this problem.
I tired the modifications you suggested but I was still unable to get the ColorViewr to work. On the Xaml, I now have the following binding parameter:
<kt:KinectColorViewer Width="200" Height="200" Grid.Column="3" KinectSensorManager="{Binding KinectSensorManager}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="76,186,0,0" Name="kinectColorViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
And the changes you mentioned are made to the code in behind. Still it seems like the sensor is not connected to the Colorviwer

Comment: Can you edit your original post and add both your XAML and code-behind to the end of the post?

Comment: I have modified my answer with some more details based on your update.

Comment: Can someone help me with one question, i have some User Controls that uses the Kinect Sensor, so i want to handle the sensor discovering and configuration in my MainWindow, and put it available to my UserControls, i do this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774456/handling-kinect-in-main-window-and-passing-this-reference-to-usercontrols) question here on StackOverflow, any help will be apreciated.