# Handling Kinect in Main Window and passing this reference to UserControls

Tags: wpf, user-controls, kinect

I have a project in WPF with a lot of UserControls, some user controls uses Kinect KinectColorViewer.xaml
I want to handle the sensor discovering and setup (conect, disconect, etc) in main window and serve it to my UserControls, how is the best way to do it?

[Here](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7317021_68786065_117250) is the project that explains my question.

If you prefer, [here](https://github.com/Ewerton/KinectWithUserControls.git) are the github link.

Comment: what output does a Kinect give ?

Comment: eran otzer the kinect give 3 outputs, Color, Depht, Skeleton, i want this 3 outputs available to my UserControls

Comment: is it possible just to create a property encapsulating the sensor results  and bind it OneWay to a designated dependency  property in your 
UserControl ?

Comment: seems interesting, have you some code example?

Answer (score 3):

From your example code,

Assuming you want to maintain as much of the already available code from Microsoft, you will want to set up a reference to the KinectSensorManager on initializing your application.  My constructor normally looks something like this:

```
private readonly KinectSensorChooser sensorChooser = new KinectSensorChooser();

public KinectSensorManager KinectSensorManager { get; private set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
    // initialize the Kinect sensor manager
    KinectSensorManager = new KinectSensorManager();
    KinectSensorManager.KinectSensorChanged += this.KinectSensorChanged;

    // locate an available sensor
    sensorChooser.Start();

    // bind chooser's sensor value to the local sensor manager
    var kinectSensorBinding = new Binding("Kinect") { Source = this.sensorChooser };
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.KinectSensorManager, KinectSensorManager.KinectSensorProperty, kinectSensorBinding);
}
```

The KinectSensorManager is just a helper class.  You can rewrite code to easily avoid using it, but it doesn't do anything bad (does a lot of nice stuff for you) so I've just keep using it.  Also, since I'm assuming you want to re-use as much code as possible, we want to maintain its usage.

For your control, you can extend KinectControl which will set up a bunch of helpful items for you.  So...

```
public partial class KinectUserControl : KinectControl
{
  ...
}
```

This will give your control access to a lot of override-able functions that listen in to various events (like KinectSensorChanged).  Check our the KinectColorViewer code and you can see how it overrides this function, which allows it to automatically start displaying new data if you swap Kinects.

When declaring your control in the XAML you can now add a reference to the KinectSensorManager:

```
<my:KinectUserControl KinectSensorManager="{Binding KinectSensorManager}" />
```

Because your control now has a KinectSensorManager property, it should pass through to your KinectColorViewer control as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You got exactly what i need! I based myself in the KinectExplorer project and ended up with this problem. My UserControl references the KinectColorViewer of the samples, when i run it, i have an exception. Tonight, i will implement it in a separate project, test your sugestion and publish it on github, to provide you more information.

Comment: Hey Evil Closet Monkey, here (https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D7317021_68786065_117250) is the project that explains this question. My approach is send a KinectSersor object to UserControl. Can you take a look on this?

Comment: Ewerton, I get a proxy error when trying to access your files.  Could be my work proxy, where I normally check up here during breaks.  If it is possible to post the important bits here, or put the files on GitHub (or similar) that would give me and other a chance to look at them.

Comment: i already edited the question with the git link here is a shortcut  (https://github.com/Ewerton/KinectWithUserControls)

Comment: seems i've missing the KinectControl extend. Will try it tonight. Thanks a lot

Comment: hi @Evil Closet Monkey, iam implemented your solution but it still not working. I updated the GitHub project, can you download it and give a look?

Comment: Add "DataContext = this;" to your MainWindow.xaml.cs constructor.

Comment: Ewerton, any success with the above?

Comment: i dont test it yet, but, as soon as possible, i will test and post the results.