# KinectColorViewer and SDK 1.6

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, kinect

I'm new to Kinect and VS Development, and I was using the [Windows Kinect Quickstart Series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart), but unfortunately, it was meant for Kinect SDK v1.00.

I got stuck on KinectColorView usage, and I'cant proceed (I have been Googlin' for 2 days now). I also found this very similar question: [Using KinectColorViewer in SDK1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609858/using-kinectcolorviewer-in-sdk1-5) here on StackOverflow but couldn't solve my problem. I know that I'm close, but i need help.

**The problem is: that I can't get my KinectColorViewer to work.**

I added it to the XAML designer, but it seems I can't bind it to the SensorManager. 
Here is my XAML code:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfViewers="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers;assembly=Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers" xmlns:Toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit;assembly=Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="KinectSetupDev.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1024" Loaded="Window_Loaded_1" Closed="Window_Closed_1">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="736" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1012" Margin="2,2,0,0">
         <TextBlock x:Name="tbMessages" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" Margin="10,662,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="992"/>
         <WpfViewers:KinectColorViewer x:Name="KinectColorViewer" KinectSensorManager="{Binding KinectSensorManager}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="240" Margin="608,27,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="320" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Nothing to report about the XAML code, except that i had to add the chunk

```
"KinectSensorManager="{Binding KinectSensorManager}"
```

in the KinectColorViewer item by writing it, because I couldn't find the way to this by the XAML designer's GUI (so I have some doubts about its viability).

Here is my code-behind (*I almost totally copied it by the question: [Using KinectColorViewer in SDK1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609858/using-kinectcolorviewer-in-sdk1-5) so I can't understand why it's not working!!*)

```
namespace KinectSetupDev
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    // Automatically finds a Kinect for you.
    private readonly KinectSensorChooser sensorChooser = new KinectSensorChooser();

    public KinectSensorManager KinectSensorManager01 { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

    }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the Kinect sensor manager.
        KinectSensorManager01 = new KinectSensorManager();
        KinectSensorManager01.KinectSensorChanged += this.KinectSensorChanged;

        // Locate an available sensor.
        sensorChooser.Start();

        // Bind chooser's sensor value to the local sensor manager.
        var kinectSensorBinding = new Binding("Kinect") { Source = this.sensorChooser };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.KinectSensorManager01, KinectSensorManager.KinectSensorProperty, kinectSensorBinding);
    }

    private void Window_Closed_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UninitializeKinectServices(KinectSensorManager01.KinectSensor);
    }

    #region Kinect Discovery & Setup

    private void KinectSensorChanged(object sender, KinectSensorManagerEventArgs<KinectSensor> args)
    {
        if (null != args.OldValue)  
            UninitializeKinectServices(args.OldValue);

        if (null != args.NewValue)
            InitializeKinectServices(KinectSensorManager01, args.NewValue);
    }

    // Kinect enabled apps should customize which Kinect services it initializes here.
    private void InitializeKinectServices(KinectSensorManager kinectSensorManager, KinectSensor sensor)
    {
        // Application should enable all streams first.
        kinectSensorManager.ColorStreamEnabled = true;
        kinectSensorManager.DepthStreamEnabled = true;
        kinectSensorManager.SkeletonStreamEnabled = true;

        // Start the sensor!
        try
        {
            sensor.Start();
            sensorChooser.Kinect.ElevationAngle = 10;
            tbMessages.Text = "Kinect Started";
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException)
        {
            sensor = null;
            tbMessages.Text = "Kinect Not Started" + "\r";
        }
    }

    // Kinect enabled apps should uninitialize all Kinect services that were initialized in InitializeKinectServices() here.
    private void UninitializeKinectServices(KinectSensor sensor)
    {
        if (sensor != null)
        {

            if (sensor.IsRunning)
            {
                sensorChooser.Kinect.ElevationAngle = 0;
                sensor.Stop();
                sensor.AudioSource.Stop();

            }
        }
    }

    #endregion Kinect Discovery & Setup

  }
}
```

I tried to add the line  `DataContext = this;`  in the contructor, but it does not work.

**The application runs, my Kinect starts but the KinectColorViewer does not show anything.**

*Moreover, can anyone tell the difference between*  `sensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();` 
*and*  `kinectSensorManager.SkeletonStreamEnabled = true;`  *??*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your XAML you bind to `KinectSensorManager`, which doesn't exist.  You are calling it `KinectSensorManager01` in your code, so you need to properly reflect that in your XAML.

That will likely fix it.  But another thing I see is that you're accessing the sensor in at least 3 different ways.  This gets at your second question.

You are doing the same thing with `sensor.SkeletonStream.Enabled()` and `kinectSensorManager.SkeletonStreamEnabled = true`, you're just going about it in a different way.  The `KinectSensorManager` is a data model wrapped around the Kinect hardware which manages a lot of mundane little things for you.  If you are going to use it (I personally do all the time) then you should always use it to access the hardware.  This will ensure your references never fall out of sync.

So, in your `InitializeKinectServer` function you do not want to be using `sensor.Start()` and `sensorChooser.Kinect.ElevationAngle`.  You want to be using the corresponding `KinectSensorManager` calls.

Here is a quick and dirty application to show just the KinectColorChooser:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SimpleKinectStart.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewer="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers;assembly=Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <viewer:KinectColorViewer KinectSensorManager="{Binding KinectSensorManager}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using Microsoft.Kinect;
using Microsoft.Kinect.Toolkit;
using Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers;

namespace SimpleKinectStart
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private readonly KinectSensorChooser _sensorChooser = new KinectSensorChooser();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = this;

            if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
            {
                // do something special, only for design mode
            }
            else
            {
                KinectSensorManager = new KinectSensorManager();
                KinectSensorManager.KinectSensorChanged += OnKinectSensorChanged;

                _sensorChooser.Start();

                if (_sensorChooser.Kinect == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to detect an available Kinect Sensor");
                    Application.Current.Shutdown();
                }

                // Bind the KinectSensor from the sensorChooser to the KinectSensor on the KinectSensorManager
                var kinectSensorBinding = new Binding("Kinect") { Source = _sensorChooser };
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(this.KinectSensorManager, KinectSensorManager.KinectSensorProperty, kinectSensorBinding);
            }
        }

        #region Kinect Discovery & Setup

        private void OnKinectSensorChanged(object sender, KinectSensorManagerEventArgs<KinectSensor> args)
        {
            if (null != args.OldValue)
                UninitializeKinectServices(args.OldValue);

            if (null != args.NewValue)
                InitializeKinectServices(KinectSensorManager, args.NewValue);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize Kinect based services.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kinectSensorManager"></param>
        /// <param name="sensor"></param>
        private void InitializeKinectServices(KinectSensorManager kinectSensorManager, KinectSensor sensor)
        {
            // configure the color stream
            kinectSensorManager.ColorFormat = ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30;
            kinectSensorManager.ColorStreamEnabled = true;

            // configure the depth stream
            kinectSensorManager.DepthStreamEnabled = true;

            kinectSensorManager.TransformSmoothParameters =
                new TransformSmoothParameters
                {
                    // as the smoothing value is increased responsiveness to the raw data
                    // decreases; therefore, increased smoothing leads to increased latency.
                    Smoothing = 0.5f,
                    // higher value corrects toward the raw data more quickly,
                    // a lower value corrects more slowly and appears smoother.
                    Correction = 0.5f,
                    // number of frames to predict into the future.
                    Prediction = 0.5f,
                    // determines how aggressively to remove jitter from the raw data.
                    JitterRadius = 0.05f,
                    // maximum radius (in meters) that filtered positions can deviate from raw data.
                    MaxDeviationRadius = 0.04f
                };

            // configure the skeleton stream
            kinectSensorManager.SkeletonStreamEnabled = true;

            // enable the sensor
            kinectSensorManager.KinectSensorEnabled = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Uninitialize all Kinect services that were initialized in InitializeKinectServices.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sensor"></param>
        private void UninitializeKinectServices(KinectSensor sensor)
        {
            // do what needs to be done
        }

        #endregion Kinect Discovery & Setup

        #region Properties

        public KinectSensorManager KinectSensorManager { get; private set; }

        #endregion Properties
    }
}
```

When working with the `KinectSensorManager` you always want to use the wrappers supplied by the sensor manger when possible.  So you would want to use `kinectSensorManager.ElevationAngle` in the init function, or `KinectSensorManager.ElevationAngle` elsewhere (note difference between local vs. global call).  This allows the sensor manager to try and do what you ask and fail gracefully if need be.

In the `UninitializeKinectServices` function you will only ever deal with the sensor directly.  When you hit this function the `KinectSensorChooser` either selected a new Kinect or has lost it and set the sensor to `null`.  You are dealing with the *old* sensor value in this function, cleaning up services that were once linked to it.  Any reference you make to `KinectSensorManager` will either be to the new sensor or a `null` reference.

Comment: The last question is: in the UninitializeKinectServices method, I can access only to the sensor, so I can' use tha SensorManager functions. Should I use the sensor functions or pass the SensorManager as input and use his calls? I want my code to be as consistent as posssibile.
Thanks again!!!

Comment: I've added 2 paragraphs to my answer above to address your comment questions.

Answer (score 0):

I added Path property manually and it works for me:

```
<WpfViewers:KinectColorViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="221" Margin="75,84,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="372" Kinect="{Binding ElementName=kinectSensorChooser1, Mode=OneWay,Path=Kinect}"/>
```